# If $R$ is a partial order on $[n],$ prove that $|R| \le n(n+1) / 2$

Tags: order-theory

I have to prove that:

> if $R$ is partial order on $[n],$ then $|R| \le n(n+1) / 2.$

Because a partial order is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive
we know that:

- for all $a$ in $[n],$ $(a,a)$ belong to $R,$
- if $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,a)\in R,$ then $a=b,$
- if $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R,$ then $(a,c)\in R,$

but I don't know what to do next.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R$ be an antisymmetric relation on $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}.$ (Reflexivity and transitivity will not be used.)

For each of the $\frac{n(n-1)}2$ ordered pairs $(i,j)\in[n]^2$ such that $i<j,$ at most one of the pairs $(i,j)$ or $(j,i)$ belongs to $R.$

For each of the $n$ elements $i\in[n],$ the pair $(i,i)$ belongs to $R$ or not.

Therefore,
$$|R|\le\frac{n(n-1)}2+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2.$$

Comment: Why you ignore and reflexivity and. the transitivity?

Comment: I just don't need them. As soon as $R$ is antisymmetric, its cardinality will be upper-bounded like this.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ah, I see. I was thinking we were calculating the number of partial orders, not the number of ordered pairs. (And yes, I did think the question was very wrong.)